# Django form with multiple model instances

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating a Django app where, from a page I can add 8 images (with 8 input fields, one of them is the main image of the post) to a Blog Post. I have these 2 models:

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    file_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And the following Forms:

```
class CratePostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

class CreatePicturesPostForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.FileField()
    image_1 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_2 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_3 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_4 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_5 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_6 = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image_7 = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

I can easily create a Post with different form doing something like this:

```
pictures_form = CreatePicturesPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

and saving every image as a new Picture object with a foreign key to the Post. The problem is happening when I want to create the edit page of the form, I have to load in the form the previous uploaded images and show them to the user.

I wanted to do something like the following:

```
pictures_form = EditPicturesAdForm(instance=pictures)
```

but this instance should be a single object, while I have many instances of Pictures object coming from the same model.

Any idea?

Comment: That is what formsets are for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please provide me some example about something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to use Django Extra Views in this case. [Link](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views)

#### In your forms.py:

```
from extra_views import InlineFormSet


class PicturesInline(InlineFormSet):

        model = Pictures
        extra = 1
        max_num = 8
        fields = ('file_path',)

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', )
```

#### And in your views.py:

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, UpdateWithInlinesView

class BlogPostCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    template_name = ''
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    inlines = [PicturesInline, ]
    success_url = ''

class BlogPostUpdateView(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    template_name = ''
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    inlines = [PicturesInline, ]
    success_url = ''
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a common Django way to do that without having to install an app? Also I am new to Django and I am not using Class Views..

Comment: @giorgio you can check out official Django documentation on [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/) for additional information.